# How to solve 'Parse error syntax error unexpected end of file' in PHP file?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have looked through my code and I don't know why this error keeps arising.

The exact error message I get
**'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\includes\functions.inc.php on line 92'**

This is my code:

```
<?php
#since this file contains solely PHP there is no need for the closing tag
#by convention it is better to check if something fails first then succeeds
function emptyInputSignup($username, $password, $passwordRepeat){
    $result = Null;
    if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

function invalidUsername($username){
    $result = Null;
    #if there is a mistake
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
function passwordMatch($password, $passwordRepeat){
    $result = Null;
    #if there has been a mistake
    if ($password !== $passwordRepeat){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

function usernameExists($conn, $username){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    #we have created a prepared statement to prevent SQL injections
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    $result = Null;
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    
    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result();
    
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)){ 
        return $row;        
        
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
        return $result;
}

function passwordValid($password){
    $result = Null;
    #if there is a mistake
    if (strlen($password) <= 5 && !preg_match("~[0-9]+~", $password)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is the function where I think the error is located in.

```
function createUser($conn, $username, $password){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
    #we have created a prepared statement to prevent SQL injections
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    #this checks if the statement is feasible
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }
    #returns hash of a password
    #this inbuilt function is constantly updated
    $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);   
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $hashedPassword);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    header("location: ../signup.php?error=none");
    exit;   
} #this is line 92 but I do not see where the issue is here
```

I have done some research on how this error is caused by a missing bracket and/or the state of the php.ini however short_open_tag was already set as on.
What caused the error?

Comment: Count brackets. Plus I see there one more typo, with error message/warning like `undefined constant`.

Comment: Try `usernameExists`.

Comment: ^ The final else statement in the usernameExists function.

Answer (score -1):

in `function usernameExists`
close the else

from:

```
function usernameExists($conn, $username){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    #we have created a prepared statement to prevent SQL injections
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    $result = Null;
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    
    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result();
    
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)){ 
        return $row;        
        
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
        return $result;
}
```

change to

```
function usernameExists($conn, $username){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    #we have created a prepared statement to prevent SQL injections
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    $result = Null;
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    
    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result();
    
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)){ 
        return $row;        
        
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
        return $result;
      }//<---this line
}
```

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].